# ** socat[8592] E connect(5, AF=1 "\0/tmp/dbus-6LCOz2lgUY", 23): Connection refused**

Tags: internet, interface, dbus, tmp, sockets

I am a BEGINNER with Ubuntu (Linux).
I am trying to create an independant network namespace (that I downloaded here : https://github.com/Lekensteyn/netns) in order to capture Internet traffic without noise.
My OS is : "Ubuntu", VERSION="18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"

The folder downloaded is called **netns**.
So here are the commands to execute for having the same bug that I had :

**In a terminal:**
[sart network namespace:]

```
sudo ~/netns/netns 0 start


# ip netns add netns0
# ip link add veth0 type veth peer name veth1
# ip link set veth1 netns netns0
# ip link set veth0 up
# ip addr add 10.9.0.1/24 dev veth0
# ip netns exec netns0 ip link set veth1 up
# ip netns exec netns0 ip addr add 10.9.0.2/24 dev veth1
# ip netns exec netns0 ip route add default via 10.9.0.1 dev veth1
# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o veth0 -j MASQUERADE
# iptables -A FORWARD -i veth0 -j ACCEPT
# iptables -A FORWARD -o veth0 -j ACCEPT
# Done!
```

[External access]

```
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlp1s0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo sed -n '/nameserver/!p' /etc/resolv.conf > new_resolv.conf
sudo mv new_resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
sudo echo nameserver 1.1.1.1 >> /etc/resolv.conf


net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

**In a other terminal**:

[For access to external (LAN or internet) hosts, firefox in my case]

```
sudo ~/netns/netns 0 exec
firefox
```

Even if firefox would open, we got this error:

**2021/03/24 19:03:07 socat[8592] E connect(5, AF=1 "\0/tmp/dbus-6LCOz2lgUY", 23): Connection refused**

Can you help me to solve this problem please?
Thank you

Comment: What OS & release are you asking about?   This isn't a generic Linux support site (Stack Exchange *Unix & Linux* provides that function).

Comment: Thank you @guiverc for your comment. My OS is : "Ubuntu", VERSION="18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)" . I made an update.